# How to create an oracle plsql function that will return multiple rows for a specific parameter (ex: employee id)

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I need to create a function that will be called on oracle screen.
I just don't know how to do it

Comment: What will the function do? What application environment is an "oracle screen"? Most likely you will need to consult the documentation for the client programming environment you are using and the Oracle interface it employs to connect to the database. There are many of those out there, and they're all different.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is function that returns refcursor.

This is example based on Scott's sample `emp` table; function accepts department number as a parameter and returns data related to employees working in that department.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_deptno in emp.deptno%type)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open l_rc for
  7      select deptno, empno, ename, job, sal
  8      from emp
  9      where deptno = par_deptno;
 10    return l_rc;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test(10) from dual;

F_TEST(10)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10       7782 CLARK      MANAGER       2572.5
        10       7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5250
        10       7934 MILLER     CLERK           1365


SQL>
```